# Tomcat Restful API 404

Tags: json, rest, tomcat

GET api/users/1

Here's the situation:
if user 1 does not exist, respond a 404 http status code and a json message.
The json message would like this:

```
{
  "message": "Resouces `api/users/1` does not exist"
  "error_code": 1000
}
```

And here's the code:

```
if(user == null) {
        Map<String, Object> error = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        error.put("message", "Resource `api/users/" + id + "` does not exist!");
        error.put("error_code", 1000);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
```

But tomcat returns a default error page without the response body:
[image]

What should I do, if I want a page like below:

[image]

Comment: Show your controller class and web mvc configurations

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning error object return custom json object with status codes , or you can use error-page element which specifies mapping between error page and a handler method , 

404
/error

And then in your controller hand that .

Read more  [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/how-to-custom-error-pages-in-tomcat-with-spring-mvc.html)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem myself, forget to add a ResponseBody annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Use

```
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.SC_ACCEPTED);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it out myself. I forgot to add the ResponseBody annotation to the method

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is provided by the OP and is edited out from the question.*

Forgetting to add a ResponseBody annotation. Anyway, if declared the controller with the @RestController annotation, it won't be necessary.